# Postgres image from docker can't find initdb. What am I missing?

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgresql-initdb

I'm on windows 10 with docker version 1.9.1 using docker toolbox
I wanted to put up a quick postgres container, something I've done before with a dockerfile I had laying around.

```
FROM postgres

ADD create-db.sql /tmp/
ADD drop_create_table.sql /tmp/
ADD db.sql /tmp/

ADD create-db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

It's pretty simple.
and when i run the resulting image. it starts fine.
However at the end it says:

> ...
>
> server started ALTER ROLE
>
> /docker-entrypoint-sh: running
>
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-db.sh :No such file or directory

If I try to do `docker run -it <imagename> //bin/bash` I can see that the file is indeed there:

> root@xxxx:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d# ls
>
> create-db.sh

but whenever I run it it tells me it's not.
The container promptly stops when it doesn't find the file, so I can't try to ssh into the running container.

Comment: Can you try with a `RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` before your `ADD`?

Comment: Show `docker-entrypoint-sh` file